# mongodb: when using $all, the query execution time depends on the order of the input parameters

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a toy mongodb collection with the following structure

```
{
    "operation" : {
        "type" : "STACK"
    },
    "constraints" : [{
        "partNumbers" : ["part", "part_1"]
    }]
}
```

I want to query the documents with the specified type and partNumbers, so I wrote this query

```
db.getCollection('toy').find({
   "operation.type" : "STACK",
   "constraints.partNumbers": {"$all": ["part_1", "part"]}
})
```

and the index

```
db.toy.ensureIndex( { 
   "operation.type": 1, 
   "constraints.partNumbers": 1,
})
```

I created a dataset with some millions documents, with almost all of them having "part" in the partNumbers array

The query is very fast (it takes 1 ms), but if I swap "part" and "part1", it takes forever (more than 2 seconds on my dataset).

It looks like mongodb uses the index only on the first element that I pass in the "$all" function of the query.

this is the result of explain() for the query that executes fast

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "factorysim.robofacturingservice",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [ 
            {
                "constraints" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "$and" : [ 
                            {
                                "partNumbers" : {
                                    "$size" : 2
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "constraintType" : {
                                    "$eq" : "PART_NUMBER_CONSTRAINT"
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "partNumbers" : {
                                    "$eq" : "part_1"
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "partNumbers" : {
                                    "$eq" : "part"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "operation.type" : {
                    "$eq" : "STACK"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "constraints" : {
                "$elemMatch" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "partNumbers" : {
                                "$eq" : "part_1"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "partNumbers" : {
                                "$size" : 2
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "constraintType" : {
                                "$eq" : "PART_NUMBER_CONSTRAINT"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "partNumbers" : {
                                "$eq" : "part"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "operation.type" : 1.0,
                "constraints.partNumbers" : 1.0
            },
            "indexName" : "operation.type_1_constraints.partNumbers_1",
            "isMultiKey" : true,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "operation.type" : [],
                "constraints.partNumbers" : [ 
                    "constraints", 
                    "constraints.partNumbers"
                ]
            },
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "operation.type" : [ 
                    "[\"STACK\", \"STACK\"]"
                ],
                "constraints.partNumbers" : [ 
                    "[\"part_1\", \"part_1\"]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : []
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "p1",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.6.8",
    "gitVersion" : "8e540c0b6db93ce994cc548f000900bdc740f80a"
},
"ok" : 1.0
}
```

and for the one that executes slow

```
{
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "factorysim.robofacturingservice",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {
        "$and" : [ 
            {
                "constraints" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "$and" : [ 
                            {
                                "partNumbers" : {
                                    "$size" : 2
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "constraintType" : {
                                    "$eq" : "PART_NUMBER_CONSTRAINT"
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "partNumbers" : {
                                    "$eq" : "part"
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "partNumbers" : {
                                    "$eq" : "part_1"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }, 
            {
                "operation.type" : {
                    "$eq" : "STACK"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
        "filter" : {
            "constraints" : {
                "$elemMatch" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "partNumbers" : {
                                "$eq" : "part"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "partNumbers" : {
                                "$size" : 2
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "constraintType" : {
                                "$eq" : "PART_NUMBER_CONSTRAINT"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "partNumbers" : {
                                "$eq" : "part_1"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern" : {
                "operation.type" : 1.0,
                "constraints.partNumbers" : 1.0
            },
            "indexName" : "operation.type_1_constraints.partNumbers_1",
            "isMultiKey" : true,
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "operation.type" : [],
                "constraints.partNumbers" : [ 
                    "constraints", 
                    "constraints.partNumbers"
                ]
            },
            "isUnique" : false,
            "isSparse" : false,
            "isPartial" : false,
            "indexVersion" : 2,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "indexBounds" : {
                "operation.type" : [ 
                    "[\"STACK\", \"STACK\"]"
                ],
                "constraints.partNumbers" : [ 
                    "[\"part\", \"part\"]"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : []
},
"serverInfo" : {
    "host" : "p1",
    "port" : 27017,
    "version" : "3.6.8",
    "gitVersion" : "8e540c0b6db93ce994cc548f000900bdc740f80a"
},
"ok" : 1.0
```

}

Is there a way of writing a query/index combination that works independently from the order of the input parameters?

Comment: Add explained query plans for both queries to the question.

Comment: I've edited my question   @D.SM

Answer (score 0):

Both query plans appear to be identical, therefore the assertion that

> the index usage depends on the order of the input array

appears to be unsupported by evidence.

Comment: Actually, if you look carefully there is a difference.

The first plan says   
    "constraints.partNumbers" : [ 
      "[\"part_1\", \"part_1\"]"
    ]
                
and the second  
    "constraints.partNumbers" : [ 
      "[\"part\", \"part\"]"
    ].               
                
The query using the index to filter documents having "part_1" is faster because "part_1" is less frequent than "part"

Comment: The same index is used in the same way. The fact that you are querying with different values doesn't affect index choice.

Comment: OK, if your question is about your specific execution you also should provide sample data that reproduces the behavior you are seeing. And I don't see execution stats in your question, research what those are and add them.